# How to find the selected checkboxes in mvc form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My viewModel contains List of Foo property (FooList). I iterate FooList by foreach on razor such as:

```
 @foreach (Foo foo in Model.FooList)
                    { <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="False" name="@foo.Id"/></td>
                        <td>@foo.Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
```

And I'm checking some items then submit form. I access selected values from FormCollection. But I lost object orianted capability because I need string parses operations etc.
What is the bestpractice for?

Comment: Use a strongly typed model in `POST` operation? I see no reason to move back to `FormCollection`. That way the problem will be non-existent, 'cause you will have a collection of objects with appropriate properties set to either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem in MVC as it's difficult bind your list of checkboxes when posting back to your model.

I've used this extension before which made the scenario much simpler. [CheckBoxList(For)](http://mvccbl.com/) The instructions are pretty straightforward and the package is available on Nuget.